# ASP MVC site-wide META tag customization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, web-config

I'm developing a simple CMS using ASP MVC and I have plan to deploy the `CMS` to a `few domains with different title, meta tag` and a few site-wide configuration. I'm using ASP MVC and believe Razor can help inject the custom meta tag before serving the page.

My question is - should I save the configuration in web.config? or I should just save in in a static site-wide variable? then pass them to the view and spit it using razor when my page is serve?

`Web.config? or a static variable is better?`

Comment: What is exactly your question is about? Perfomance? Example? I think you understand that your static property can return value from WebConfig.

Comment: My question is performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive it's not really metter use Web.Config or static variable unless you have really high load site. Becouse `Web.Config` get's cached once application starts and if it changes `IIS` track the changes and load it again in memory. Static valiable, in general, is in memory too.

I recommend use `Web.Config`, but only becouse of opportunity make changes to your meta tags and not rebuild solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your domain name for access to a partial view from `_Layout.cshtml`:

F.e.

```
<html>
<head>
@Html.Partial(Request.Uri.Host);
. . .
</head>
```

For domain names `domain1.tld` and `domain2.tld` you must create shared views `domain1.tld.cshtml` and `domain2.tld.cshtml` with similar content:

```
<title>domain 1 title<title>
<meta name="description" content="domain 1 descritpion" />
```